# WooCommerce Checkout Issue specific to Instagram In-App Browser

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, instagram

This is probably one of the strangest and most frustrating issues I've come across. We have a website https://scampanddude.com/ that is an online shop using, WordPress and WooCommerce.

A lot of their marketing is done via their Instagram page https://www.instagram.com/scampanddude/. When the website is opened from the Instagram app it opens in Instagram's in-app browser. Everything seems to work fine until you get to the checkout. The payment options section is greyed out and the card fields are squashed. If you open the same page on desktop browsers or mobile browsers this section is fine and works as it is supposed to.

I have tried moving this to staging and disabling all of the plugins except WooCommerce and also with the Twentynineteen and Storefront themes and the issue occurs with all of these configurations.

I know that other WordPress and WooCommerce website don't experience this issue so I am at a bit of a loss trying to find out what is causing it.

Comment: This issue is related to the Instagram In-App Browser and you should report it to Instagram (and/or WooCommerce) as StackOverflow community don't handle any software support, so your question is off topic here.

Comment: Is just not the right place for this kind of help.

Answer (score 4):

You should reach out to your hosting provider asking if "bots redirecting" feature is activated for your site. This has been a confirmed cause of WooCommerce checkout page stuck loading its contents on several sites I reviewed.

The actual problem is that ajax call to `/?wc-ajax=update_order_review` on checkout,  instead of reaching and being processed by WooCommerce backend, is redirected to the site homepage by the server with "bots redirecting" turned on.

Disabling "bots redirecting" should result in the issue being resolved. Here are instructions on how to [do it on WP Engine hosting](https://wpengine.com/support/redirecting-bots-how-this-benefits-you/).

Comment: Thank you very much this solve my problem you are really a life savior trying to solve this problem frm last many days and finally its done thank you very much

Comment: Thank you so much! Helped me out as well!

Comment: how about other hosting? can we do it via `.htaccess` ?