# Instagram In-App Browser $_GET variables not working

Tags: get, instagram

I have a checkout page written in PHP that uses affiliate tracking.

Many affiliates like to advertise via Instagram.

When using the Instagram In App Browser on mobile phones anything within the code that relies on the $_GET variable is failing as it never seems to have any available data.

Thoroughly tested and issue is specifically with the Instagram browser,  Facebook browser works as expected.

I can detect the Instagram browser ok via User Agent to do a bit of damage control but don't have a full working solution.

I attempted to force my page open in native browsers on the phone but couldn't get it to work, it was just refreshing the page In-App.

I've attempted loading scripts in iFrames to get needed data but those seem to be blocked as well when going through the In App Browser.

Open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This resolved the issue for me.

WP Engine host Redirecting Bots

[WooCommerce Checkout Issue specific to Instagram In-App Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57802180/woocommerce-checkout-issue-specific-to-instagram-in-app-browser?rq=1)